# "Recent Items" menu item disappears from Apple menu

Tags: macos, menu-bar

## Disappearing "Recent Items" menu item

Since upgrading to El Capitan 10.11.1, the "Recent Items" menu item from the Apple menu disappears. Even during a work session, sometimes "Recent Items" is there when I need it, sometimes it disappears altogether.

[image]

## Multiple Items on Submenu

Furthermore, when the menu does mysteriously return it has multiple items repeating in the list of the "Recent Items" submenu.

Is this a common El Capitan bug? Should I have done a clean install instead of an upgrade? Any way to fix either problem, the disappearing menu item or the multiple submenu items?

[image]

Comment: Also being discussed here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211471/recent-items-menus-have-stopped-working-on-my-imac

Comment: I did a clean install of El Capitan, and I have the exact same problem. I would love to have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Rebuild `LaunchServices` Library

From this discussion board I learned to "rebuild the LaunchServices library". I do not understand the details, but this one line executed in Terminal.app does the trick:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Then restart your Mac. Relaunching the Finder is not enough, you must restart your Mac to get back your Recent Items menu.

**Good news:** It works.

**Bad news:** The effect is temporary. Eventually (days, weeks) your Recent Items menu will either disappear or develop duplicates.

Because this is only a partial workaround, and not a true fix, I will not mark this Answer (my own) as Accepted. Hopefully someone else might post a real fix.

I suspect, but have not proven, that the real solution is a clean-install. I took some bad advice and upgraded in-place to Mavericks and El Capitan. Next time I do a major upgrade I will go back to the tried-and-true method of a clean install.

Comment: Update: Seems like this bug has been fixed by updates subsequently issued by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

go to System Preferences > General, the Recent Items usually resets to None.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions