# Can I hIde "Documents" from "Apple>Recent Items" menu?

Tags: menu-bar

I often use `>Recent Items` to select recent applications and servers, but I *never* user it for recent documents. Is there a way to remove `Documents` from this menu while retaining `Applications` and `Servers`.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211471/recent-items-menus-have-stopped-working-on-my-imac has some ideas on what to look for if it breaks, but I can't see anywhere where you can set Docs/Apps/Servers to different values. The global parameter is in Prefs > General